Queue up multiple 401 failed requests to avoid getting spammed with 401s
In our React app using Redux-Saga and Axios, around 30 requests are made on page load. When the token expires, all requests receive 401 status codes. Each request tries to handle the 401 status code individually and redirect to /login, causing the page to flicker between /settings and /login for some time, depending on how many requests fail with 401. This also floods our Application Insights logs with 401 errors every morning.
Desired Behavior:

Only the first 401 error should trigger session invalidation.
Subsequent requests should wait until the session is invalidated.

In the image below, you can see that all requests return 401 status codes and it doesn't stop after the first one:

Here's an example of how these requests are made:
const requestURL = yield new URL(`${apiRoutes.base}/${contractsCancel}`);

const { responseData, responseError } = yield call(
    genericRequest,
    requestURL,
    httpMethod.Put,
);

I found a useful implementation on Stack Overflow which handles multiple failed requests. Although we don't have refresh tokens, the managing multiple failed requests part could be the key. Any ideas how I can solve the issue with minimal code changes?
Snippet
request.ts
async function request(
    url: string,
    options?: AxiosRequestConfig,
): Promise<{} | { err: AxiosError }> {
    const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
    if (!options) {
        options = { cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token };
    } else {
        options = Object.assign(options, {
            cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token,
        });
    }
    const promise = axios(url, options).then(parseJSON);

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    (promise as any)[CANCEL] = () => {
        // cancel XHR request, called by redux-saga when a saga gets cancelled
        cancelTokenSource.cancel(CANCEL_OPERATION);
    };

    return promise;
}

export function* genericRequest(
    url: URL,
    method: httpMethod,
    data: unknown = null,
    showNotification = true,
    params: object | null = null,
    calledWithSchema = noSchemaSymbol,
) {
    if (
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' &&
        calledWithSchema !== withSchemaSymbol
    ) {
        console.log(
            `DEPRECATED: switch to requestWithSchema for type-safe requests (${method} ${url.pathname})\nIf you're working on this part of the code, consider updating the sagas`,
        );
    }
    const authUser = yield* select(selectAuthUser);

    if (!authUser) {
        console.trace('User not authenticated');

        return {
            responseData: null,
            responseError: {},
        };
    }
    const options = getOptions(method, data, authUser.accessToken, params);

    try {
        const response: GenericResponse = (yield* call(
            request,
            url.href,
            options,
        )) as GenericResponse;
        if (response.type === 4) {
            const responseError: GenericError = { detail: response.message };

            if (showNotification) {
                yield* put(
                    globalActions.addNotification({
                        type: CustomNotificationTypes.ERROR,
                        message: response.message || undefined,
                    }),
                );
            }

            return {
                responseData: null,
                responseError,
            };
        } else {
            return {
                responseData: response.data || true,
                responseError: null,
            };
        }
    } catch (error) {
        //refers to Warning code
        if (
            isAxiosError(error) &&
            error.response?.status === RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE.UNAUTHORIZED
        ) {
            yield* put(
                actions.startManageSession({
                    sessionAction: SessionActions.removeSession,
                }),
            );
            // FIXME: Use react routing, interceptor will be a nice approach to modulize request
            // history.replace('/login');
            window.location.replace('/login');
        }
        if (isAxiosError(error) && error.response?.data?.Type === 2) {
            const responseError: GenericError = {
                title: error.name,
                detail: error.response.data.Message,
                data: error.response.data.Data,
                status: error.response?.data.Type,
            };
            return {
                responseData: null,
                responseError,
            };
        } else {
            // refers to Error
            const responseError: GenericError = {
                title: error instanceof Error ? error.name : 'Unknown Error',
                detail: isAxiosError(error)
                    ? (error.response?.data?.Message ?? error.message)
                    : error instanceof Error
                        ? error.message
                        : undefined,
            };

            if (showNotification) {
                yield* put(
                    globalActions.addNotification({
                        type: CustomNotificationTypes.ERROR,
                        title: responseError.title,
                        message: responseError.detail ?? undefined,
                    }),
                );
            }
            return {
                responseData: null,
                responseError,
            };
        }
    }
}

session-saga.ts
export function* manageSession(action: PayloadAction<any>) {
    const sessionAction: SessionActions = action.payload.sessionAction;
    const accessToken = action.payload.accessToken;

    try {
        if (sessionAction === SessionActions.getSession) {
            const hrvst = window.localStorage.getItem(SESSION_NAME);
            const session = hrvst && JSON.parse(hrvst);
            const { userAccount, userInfo } = mapUser(session.accessToken);
            if (!userAccount || !userInfo) {
                yield put(
                    actions.manageSessionError({ detail: SessionErrors.invalidToken }),
                );
                return;
            }
            yield put(actions.setUserAccount(userAccount));
            yield put(actions.setUserInfo(userInfo));
            yield put(actions.sessionLoadedFromLocalStorage());
            yield put(actions.loadInitData());
        } else if (sessionAction === SessionActions.removeSession) {
            yield put(actions.setUserAccount(null));
            yield put(actions.setUserInfo(null));
            window.localStorage.removeItem(SESSION_NAME);
            window.localStorage.removeItem(FILTERS_FOR_CONTRACTS);
            window.localStorage.removeItem(FILTERS_FOR_OFFERS);
            window.localStorage.removeItem(FILTERS_FOR_REVIEW_AND_RELEASE);
            window.localStorage.removeItem(FILTERS_FOR_ORIGINATOR_SCREEN);
        } else if (sessionAction === SessionActions.setSession && accessToken) {
            const { userAccount, userInfo } = mapUser(accessToken);
            if (!userAccount || !userInfo) {
                yield put(
                    actions.manageSessionError({ detail: SessionErrors.invalidToken }),
                );
                return;
            }
            window.localStorage.setItem(
                SESSION_NAME,
                JSON.stringify({ accessToken: accessToken }),
            );

            //save the initial filter DATA at localStorage
            Object.entries(initialFilters).forEach(([key, value]) =>
                localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value)),
            );

            yield put(actions.setUserAccount(userAccount));
            yield put(actions.setUserInfo(userInfo));
            yield put(actions.sessionFromService());
            yield put(actions.loadInitData());
            yield put(actions.getCommoditiesCropYearsExpired());
        }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(
            actions.manageSessionError({
                detail: error instanceof Error ? error.message : null,
            }),
        );
    }
}

Login/index.tsx
interface locationStateType {
    from: { pathname: string };
}

export const Login = () => {
    const { t: translate } = useTranslation();
    const { state } = useLocation<locationStateType>();
    const authUser = useSelector(selectAuthUser);
    const userInfo = useSelector(selectUserInfo);
    const sessionCheck = useSelector(selectSessionCheck);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(
            actions.startManageSession({ sessionAction: SessionActions.getSession }),
        );
    }, [dispatch]);

    const fromRoute = state && state.from ? state.from.pathname : '/';
    const excludedRoutes = ['/', '/login'];
    const redirectTo = (
        <Redirect
            to={{
                pathname: excludedRoutes.indexOf(fromRoute) > 0 ? '/' : fromRoute,
            }}
        />
    );

    const loginForm = (
        <>
            <div className="login">
                <main className="login__site">
                    <Button
                        data-testid="login-button"
                        className="login__site-login-btn"
                        href={AUTH_URL}
                    >
                        {translate(translations.app.containers.Login.loginButton)}
                    </Button>
                    <a href={RESET_PASSWORD_URL} className="login__site-forget-pass">
                        {translate(translations.app.containers.Login.forgotPassword)}
                    </a>
                </main>
            </div>
        </>
    );

    return !authUser && !userInfo && sessionCheck ? loginForm : redirectTo;
};


https://gist.github.com/mkjiau/650013a99c341c9f23ca00ccb213db1c?permalink_comment_id=4471792#gistcomment-4471792 "all requests perform sequentially and if i get one 401 response, all other go to queue and relieve only after token refresh, so i don't get more then one 401" -> this is the desired behavior I need, just no refresh token
